# Pakistan NICOP no longer says NICOP

Tags: paperwork, pakistani-citizens

I had my NIC converted to NICOP and the new card that I have does not read NICOP. It just says National ID Card. Is that the same thing? There is no clear answer on NADRA web site.

Will I be allowed to board with this card?

Comment: Is there really no one in here on this forum that can answer this question?

Comment: Please report back on your experience.